# Kendo UI treelist hide button

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI TreeList & Grid for jquery. I want to hide a command button based on row values. In grid, I attached dataBound event to evaluate the model value and show/hide command button, below codes works fine

```
dataBound:function(e){
var delButton = e.container.find(".k-grid-Delete");
if (...) delButton.hide();
}
```

For TreeList, the same code seems also fine. However, when I add inline edit featrue, the same codes works differently.
  When click "Edit" or "Add", the grid stay the original visible status, but treelist show all the button.
  When click "Cancel", I triggered dataBound event in cancel event so the UI can be refreshed, then the grid show correctly but treelist still show all the buttons even if the dataBound is executed with correct logic.

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?
Thanks,
Ziff Dai

Comment: Would it be a problem to remove the button instead of just hide it?
delButton.remove();

Comment: Jorgen, the button will show again even if I use remove instead of hide. I also notice that if I click "collapse" icon, the removed/hidden button will also be shown. I make a break point on dataBound event and see that the button is already hidden, but after that it show again. It seems that some events occurred after dataBound that redrawn the button.

Comment: That's strange, I normally removes delete/change buttons on rows on dataBound event depending on if they should be edit/delete-able. I have in other places been forced to delay my function so that the grid has been drawn (setTimeout(myFunction, 500)), but I never had to do it on the buttons, hope someone has a good solution!